# Guitar fingering question

Tags: guitar, fingering

When I play G#/Ab on the high E string on the guitar, I use my pinky for the fourth fret, but what about all the fingers before the pinky? Can they be packed closely to my pinky? Or do all fingers have to be at their own frets like stretched? Like in a scale exercise or something?

Comment: That note is rarely played in isolation! Usually there are notes before and after it, which will be the deciders as to which finger is used for top string 4th fret. If I play around the 5th fret in A, I'm far more likely to play that G# with index! Not enough information for a helpful answer yet. If that's the highest note played, then it really doesn't matter what happens to the other fingers behind - on or off the fingerboard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're playing just this single G# it even doesn't matter which finger you use and where the other fingers are. But as Tim says there are certainly other notes (chord or melody ...) that will be added.

So you have to keep in mind what you will play as next and bring your other fingers in "pool-position" that they are ready for what they will have to play as next.